# Doxygen Multiple .dox files

Tags: doxygen

I have two `.dox` files. One contains the main page and another file
describing the lattice module. I am having a problem including `lattice.dox`
in the mainpage.

Here is `vikingr.dox` that containr the main page

```
/// \mainpage Vikingr
///
/// \section intro_sec Introduction
///
/// This is the introduction.
///
/// This manual is divided in the following sections:
/// - \subpage desc_lattice
```

And here is the lattice.dox

```
/// \subpage desc_lattice Lattice
///
/// \section sec_lattice Description 
///
/// \subsection latiswp Wallpaper (Tiling) Lattices 
///
/// Wallpaper lattices are two dimensional tilings classified 
/// into five different families: \b square, \b rhombic, 
/// \b rectangular, \b parallelogram, and \b hexagonal. 
///
/// The following gives a short review of the wallpaper families.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
/// \subpage desc_lattice Lattice
```

with

```
/// \page desc_lattice Lattice
```

The main' folder is saying the lattice doc is the *sub*-page; but the lattice doc is itself a *page* - it just happens to be subsidiary to the main page.